# Jquery hovercard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I'm using http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard , but I can't find out how to declare a var on hovercard. Every job-desc has his own ID and it should be call when hovering labels. I hope I explained well.

```
<li id="577" class="item">
    <span>
        <h3 class="padding-left"><label class="labeldesc" for="">Text</label></h3>
    </span>
    <span class="job-descr" id="hiden-577">TextTextTextTextText</span>
</li>
<li id="588" class="item">
    <span>
        <h3 class="padding-left"><label class="labeldesc" for="">Text2</label></h3>
    </span>
    <span class="job-descr" id="hiden-588">Text2Text2Text2Text2Text</span>
</li>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('.labeldesc').hovercard({
    var idhover=$(this).closest('.item').attr('id');
    detailsHTML:$("#hiden-" + idhover).html()
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a shot: http://jsfiddle.net/X2q9z/

```
$('.labeldesc').hovercard({
    onHoverIn: function() {
        var txt = $($(this).parents('li')[0]).find('.job-descr').html();
        $(this).find('.hover_text').html(txt);
    },
    detailsHTML: '<div class="hover_text"></div>'
});
```

Comment: I ended up accomplish [the same](http://jsbin.com/ebujib/edit#javascript,html,live) but rather used: `var txt = $(this).closest('.item').find('.job-descr').html();` instead...

Comment: i know it's been a while but how can i change cardImgSrc property?

Answer (score 2):

First of all your jQuery Code has issue. You cannot use var inside calling hovercard function.

I update it as you wanted. Please take a loot at this: http://jsfiddle.net/cnCmN/

```
$('.labeldesc').each(function(){
    $(this).hovercard({
        detailsHTML: $("#hiden-"+$(this).closest('.item').attr('id')).html()
    });
});
```

Comment: So this should be a simpler and  better solution?

Comment: it was exactly based on your code :-) Performance wise this way may work better because it doesn't require a lookup action on mouse over.