# Hovercard not working for multiple instances

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi  i have issue with multiple instance of hovercard, the data is passed using ajax. the hovercard works for first instance, and not for second one. please help me to fix this. jsfiddle is here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/sakirullahi/TnTzk/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two labels with the same ID. You can't have that in HTML so only the first rendered label will take that ID. Try it with classes instead:

```
var hoverHTMLDemoAjax = '<p><label class="username"></label></p>';
    $(".demo-ajax").hovercard({        
    detailsHTML: hoverHTMLDemoAjax,
    width: 100,
    delay: 500,
    onHoverIn: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {                
                $(".username").prepend("<p class='loading-text'>Loading ...</p>");
            },
            success: function (data) {   

               var justatext="testing text goes here";                   
                $(".username").html(justatext);                   
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('.loading-text').remove();
            }
        });
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brightpixel/rDGe5/

Comment: Hi, john, one more help needed.. i want to pass the hovered label's html ass argument in ajax call. so please help how to identify which label is hovered in onHoverIn: function () . Thanks

Comment: If you check out this page you can see the options for hovercard : http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard and you can then access these parts through jQuery

Comment: Thanks john, but i can't found there what i am needed. can u help with code

Comment: Try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715982/jquery-hovercard You'll have to change your code, but it is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnTzk/7/)

```
var hoverHTMLDemoAjax = '<p><label id="username"></label></p>';
$(".demo-ajax").each(function(){
   var _this = $(this);
   _this.hovercard({        
        detailsHTML: hoverHTMLDemoAjax,
        width: 100,
        delay: 500,
        onHoverIn: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/echo/json/',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function () {                
                    _this.parent().find("#username").prepend("<p class='loading-text'>Loading ...</p>");
                },
                success: function (data) {   
                   console.log(_this);
                   var justatext="testing text goes here";                   
                    _this.parent().find("#username").html(justatext);                   
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('.loading-text').remove();
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks abhidev.. Your solution is help me to overcome my second issue in specified in comments.